# How do you cancel King DeDeDe's Up Special

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

So that he enters the helpless state.

Holding downward doesn't work like it did in Brawl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tap up on the joystick to cancel the [Super Dedede Jump](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Super_Dedede_Jump).

> He is vulnerable when he lands, so one can cancel the move by tapping down in Brawl or up in SSB4 if it looks risky.

Comment: I honestly never would have guessed. it works.